# Quickbooks API for backup

Tags: api, backup, quickbooks

Does anybody know if there is a Quickbooks API available that can be used to backup the Quickbooks company file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no QuickBooks API call (either qbXML or IDS) to perform an automated backup of QuickBooks.

Answer (score 1):

Though there is not an API...
They do have a utility that runs as a scheduled task...and you can copy that command and run it as you like. Here's how...

You can get the command by first setting up a scheduled backup:

In Quickbooks click File->Back Up Company->Create Local Backup

Click Local backup radio button

Click <kbd>Options</kbd> and set what you like

Click <kbd>Next</kbd> and click a radio button with Schedule future backups

Click <kbd>Next</kbd> and <kbd>New</kbd> set your schedule and click finish

OK...now go to Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Task Scheduler
Find your task...the name will be the same as the company file name
If you double click the task... it will come up in edit mode.
Click the actions tab and then click the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button.

Copy the "Program/script" name ...it will look something like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intuit\QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions 19.0\AutoBackupEXE.exe
```

Paste this into NotePad.

Copy the "Add arguments (optional):" ... it will look something like:

```
/FQ:\QuickBooks Database ES 13.0\QuickbooksFileName.QBW /S /I1585681644
```

Paste this into NotePad.

Now...you can combine these and have a command you can put in a CMD file and run at will.
You will need to put the command in quotes...it will look something like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\...\AutoBackupEXE.exe" /FQ:\QuickBooks Database ES 13.0\QuickbooksFileName.QBW /S /I1585681644
```

I have not idea what the command parameters mean...other than /F for FileName...but I do know that the others are needed. My quess it that its a database record for the option.

Answer (score -1):

Intuit has a service that will allow you to backup company files.
You could also simply back up the company file just like any other file using any number of generic backup solutions out there.

Finally, if you would like to back up the data and resue it to build applications you can look at third party products like the one from my company: [QuickBooks Data Provider](http://rssbus.com/ado/quickbooks/). Our product backs up the QuickBooks data to a database.